# NodeJS: Send Response after MongoDB Document has been updated or created

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a nodeJS server which maintains a MongoDB and a client which sends a post request with a buildName variable in JSON.

What I am trying to do is setup an event listener that is triggered when the mongoDB document with a field matching the buildName sent by the client is updated or created. Multiple clients can be listening and must be notified if a document containing the same buildName that they pass in is updated or created.

I have tried to do polling with this method where my client just sat in a while loop and constantly asked if there was an update, however, I ran into performance issues so I switched to event listeners.

I tried a few different ways of setting up a callback when my client sends its post request which gets called whenever a document is updated and then sends that updated mongodb doc as a `res.json`. One of the ones I am using is mongoose-trigger npm module which allows me to setup event listeners for both creates and updates.

I also looked on here for possible solutions which brought me to [mongoose-trigger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-trigger) for getting events triggered on creates and updates, but still could not find an answer that satisfied using this triggering to fire off a response to a post request.

Here is a snippet of the code for creating the triggering event object:

```
10 const Events = trigger(buildSchema, {
 11   events: {
 12     create: {
 13       select: 'logFile'
 14     },
 15     update: {
 16       select: 'logFile'
 17     }
 18   },
 19   debug: true
 20 });
 21
 22 module.exports = {
 23   Build: mongoose.model('build', buildSchema),
 24   Events: Events
 25 };
```

The above snippet sets up the mongoose-trigger npm module and then in my server.js I use it on my post route which is shown below:

```
 11 const Model = require('./build');
 12 mongoose.connect('mongodb://vcdep-db/builds');
 13
 14 app.post('/get_build', function(req, res) {
 15   const buildName = req.body.buildName;
 16   console.log(buildName);
 17   Model.Events.on('create', data => {
 18     Model.Build.findById(data._id, function(err, build) {
 19       if (err) console.error(err);
 20
 21       console.log("Created model");
 22       if (build.buildName === buildName)
 23       {
 24         console.log("Document got created", build.buildName);
 26         res.json(build);
 27       }
 28
 29     });
 30   });
 31   Model.Events.on('update', data => {
 32     Model.Build.findById(data._id, function(err, build) {
 33       if (err) console.error(err);
 34
 35       console.log("Updated model");
 36       if (build.buildName === buildName)
 37       {
 38         console.log("Document got updated", build.buildName);
 40         res.json(build);
 41       }
 42
 43     });
 44   });
 45 });
```

The above code works for the first time I update or create a document, however, when I do the same process I get an `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` I believe this is because the listener that mongoose-trigger sets is not removed after I send the `res.json(build)` so when the same document gets updated again it tries to do the same `res.json` from the previous clients callback which triggers that error.

I looked into removing event listeners on here and to see if mongoose-trigger allowed for something like that but haven't found a solution yet.

I believe once I am able to unbind the trigger once the response is sent it should fix the error, but I may be wrong. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it!

Also, I am not set in stone on using mongoose-trigger so if there is a better approach with this type of event listening for mongoDB updates or creates I am more than willing to change it to something else.

Comment: @kgangadhar with the mongoose-trigger module, only one of those events should be triggered at a time. So, if the document is updated only the second one is triggered and same for the create. I also, tested it with just the update trigger so there was only one res.json as well but to no avail.

Comment: If you are using events why don't you use `Model.Events.on('end'` to send response when it completes instead of sending from 'create' and 'update'.

Comment: So me it looks as if there is a general flaw in your design. To me it looks like you want to use something like socket.io to inform the client as soon as something changed. Een if the unbinding is fixed it still looks very error prone, and it might be likely that you miss events.

Comment: @NCoop, t.niese is right. That's what in such cases

Comment: @t.niese, what you think will be the way to solve this?

Comment: @kgangadhar I don't think that it is possible to tell with the given information. Can only one client listen on `/get_build`.  If many clients listen on `/get_build`, should they be informed about the same events? Are the `update`/`change`  a result of an action the listening client does, or can it also happen by an action another client does? Does the client request an information update about a task initiated by the client itself? ...

Comment: @t.niese multiple clients need to be able to listen on /get_build. And should be notified about an update or create but only if is the same buildName that they sent on /get_build. I've edited my question to be more clear. The `update / change` happens through a server that is external which updates and creates the mongodb documents using a different route.

Comment: @kgangadhar I implemented the answer that I believe you removed which used promises and my initial testing has it working as I hoped. If you remake it I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @t.niese You are right about my design and thank you for the suggestion. Currently it is working using promises which kgangadhar suggested but I will see if I can get better results using socket.io.

Comment: @NCoop The answer of kgangadhar I will _"work"_  but you just hide the problem. You will create memory leaks. And the longer your applications runs the worser the performance will become.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the callback pairs you attached as soon as one of them has been called. To be able to do so, you cannot you anyonmous function, but have to use named functions instead:

```
app.post('/get_build', function(req, res) {
  const buildName = req.body.buildName;
  console.log(buildName);

  function onCreate(data) {
    Model.Build.findById(data._id, function(err, build) {
      if (err) console.error(err);

      console.log("Created model");
      if (build.buildName === buildName) {
        console.log("Document got created", build.buildName);

        // clean up the event listeners
        Model.Events.removeListener('create', onCreate);
        Model.Events.removeListener('update', onUpdate);

        res.json(build);
      }

    });
  }

  function onUpdate(data) {
    Model.Build.findById(data._id, function(err, build) {
      if (err) console.error(err);

      console.log("Updated model");
      if (build.buildName === buildName) {
        console.log("Document got updated", build.buildName);

        // clean up the event listeners
        Model.Events.removeListener('create', onCreate);
        Model.Events.removeListener('update', onUpdate);

        res.json(build);
      }

    });
  }

  Model.Events.on('create', onCreate);
  Model.Events.on('update', onUpdate);
});
```

But this is still a bad design, and a better way would be to use `socket.io`  or something similar for this.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! I will take your advice and look into using socket.io for this.